# How to use linebreaks from __doc__ in sphinx

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-sphinx

in an attempt to professionalise my coding skills I want to use sphinx to create the documentation as a little pet project I started.
In this project I use sqlalchemy to communicate with my MySQL database which was set up using the MySQL workbench.
During the setup I also defined comments on each table.

What I'd like to do is to include the table comments in the documentation in order to clarify what each table is supposed to do.
I am using the automapper functionalities of SQLalchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from os import  path

# DBCONF is a loaded dict. Ommitted for clarity.
DBURL = URL(**DBCONF)

#Creat DB engine 
engine = create_engine(DBURL)
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
Base = declarative_base(bind = engine)

#Example Table from the database.
class Temperature(Base):
    tablename = 'temperature'
    __table__ = Table(tablename, Base.metadata, autoload=True)
    __doc__ = insp.get_table_comment(tablename)['text']
    print(__doc__)

class Foo(object):
    """
    Foo 1

    Foo 2
    """
    print(__doc__)

class Bar(object):
    __doc__ = "Bar1 \n \nBar2"
    print(__doc__)
```

The output from the

```
print(__doc__)
```

are:

```
DBLine1 \n \n DBLine2

    Foo 1

    Foo 2

Bar1

Bar2
```

In the documentation for Foo and Bar, everything is fine, but for the Temperature object I get "DBLine1 n n DBLine2". No linebreak, no \n.

Any idea where this might come from? Perhaps the characterset of the Database?

Is it actually a good idea to do what I intend? I'm starting to doubt it.

Comment: I would suggest using proper [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), then document your classes by first generating reST stub files with [autogen](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-autogen.html), then building the docs with [apidoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html)?

Comment: I think I am going to opt for that solution in the end but I'm still curious.